# Minified CanvasJs only for Linechart

Tags: javascript, canvasjs

I googled a lot but didn't find any suitable links or answers to my query. So I would like to know whether there is any way I can integrate the line chart of CanvasJs.

If I include the **default minified version then it's nearly 460KB** which is a hell lot of big file.

As I need only LineChart as of now I would like to integrate only that. Any links for the same will be really helpful.

Don't get me wrong. Even I went through the documentation but nowhere to download individual chart js. Or might be I must be blind enough not to see. :)

Comment: I doubt there is a simple way to achieve this as they do not expose individual chart. You can download debug version and remove any unwanted chart related code but this will be long and tedious task

Comment: @Rajesh Okay will give it a try. Thank you for a blazing response.